# Реализация мультикатегорий

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день. Подскажите, как реализовать мультикатегории.

Есть запись, которой присваивается категория1, мне нужно присвоить записи к примеру категория1, категория5, категория14, ну и так далее для каждой записи различные категории.

Суть вопроса в том, как построить структуру бд, чтобы всё это не мешалось кашей?

Comment: (: что делать

Answer (score 2):

У вас стандартное отношение "многие ко многим".

Необходимы три таблицы: записи, категории, соответствие записей и категорией. В таблице соответствий - два поля: Id записи, Id категории.

[image]

Comment: это уж как то муторно. была идя записывать ид категорий в отдельную колонку в таблице записей. но я не могу продумать как их потом получить, и вывести в кликабельном виде.

Comment: и как вы собираетесь записать Id категории в таблицу записей, учитывая что категорий у записи может быть N?

Comment: ---------
id
name
cat_id
----------
1
test
1,2,3,4,5

Comment: тогда для того, чтобы получить категории для записи, вам придется парсить значения из таблицы. так делать нельзя.

Comment: ваш вариант в примере можно увидеть где?

Comment: я просто не могу понять принцип запись в третью таблицу и принцип получения информации такого рода

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/